# Receiving prop in Material UI and conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is a styled-component code block, it gets an img prop and based on the prop, it decides to load a specific image.

```
export const DialogBanner = styled.div`
  min-height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  ${({ img }) =>
     img
        ? `background-image: url(${img});`
        : `background-image: url("/img/banner.jpg");`}
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: contrast(85%);
`;

<DialogBanner img={food.img} />
```

How can I write the same thing using Material UI's useStyles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This is now legacy and was written for version 4

Using the latest version of Material-UI you would use `makeStyles` which creates a hook for use within your component. https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props

For Example.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    
    // Create our styles using passed props
    // These are `functors` it seems
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
      root: {
        backgroundImage: ({ img }) =>
          img
            ? `url(${img});`
            : `url("/img/banner.jpg");`}
      },
    });
    
    function DialogBanner(props) {
      // Separating out our children
      const { children, ...rest } = props
      // Prop containing our `img`
      const classes = useStyles(rest);
      retun <div className={classes.root>{children}</div>
    }
```